# How can I set color for just one linum in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, edit

I know we can do `(set-face-foreground 'linum "your-favorite-color")`, but how if I just wan to set the face for one line number but not all the line number. How can I do that?

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.  Please be more specific.

Comment: The [ask] page has some good tips for asking technical questions effectively. You are much more likely to get a useful answer if you ask a good question.

Answer (score 2):

The `linum-format` variable can be "a function that is called with a line number as its argument and should evaluate to a string to be shown on that line." so you can do this that way.

You'll want to examine the code of the `linum-update-window` function to see how this is used.

The following does not implement your requirement; it is just an example of how these mechanisms can be used.

Note also that Emacs 26.1 is about to be released, and it provides a completely new (and dramatically more efficient) alternative to `linum`; so if you are planning to upgrade to Emacs 26 then you probably shouldn't spend too much time on `linum`.

```el
(defvar my-linum-format-string "%4d")

(add-hook 'linum-before-numbering-hook 'my-linum-get-format-string)

(defun my-linum-get-format-string ()
  (let* ((width (length (number-to-string
                         (count-lines (point-min) (point-max)))))
         (format (concat "%" (number-to-string width) "d")))
    (setq my-linum-format-string format)))

(setq linum-format 'my-linum-format)

(defun my-linum-format (line-number)
  (propertize (format my-linum-format-string line-number) 'face 'linum))
```

I'm still not certain exactly what you want to achieve, but you can test the line number in the linum-format function and vary the formatting however you wish...

```el
(defun my-linum-format (line-number)
  (propertize (format my-linum-format-string line-number)
              'face (if (eq line-number 42)
                        'linum-froody
                      'linum)))
```